# Typescript 1.0 map files do not load

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, map-files

In VS2013 update 2 RC (Typescript 1.0 RTM) I cannot debug TypeScript files in one of my projects. I have traced this back to the map file declaration. By default my JS file contains:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=general.js.map
```

Which should be correct, the map file is in the same folder as the TS and JS files. However it doesn't work. if I manually edit the file, specifying the full path, it works:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=C:/Users/myname/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/Test/JSLib/general.js.map
```

This confuses me, because surely the browser shouldn't understand the full path, eg outside the IISExpress web site?

Can anyone suggest a way to get map files working with the first mapping? Thanks

Windows 8.1 x64, IE11

Update: the app, running through IISExpress, uses Windows authentication. if I turn this off the map files load! Also, checking the output window I see:

`SourceMap http://localhost:53524/JSLib/general.js.map read failed: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.'iexplore.exe' (Script): Loaded 'http://localhost:53524/JSLib/'.`

My IIS Express logs contain

`2014-04-12 13:58:24 ::1 GET /JSLib/general.js.map - 53524 - ::1 - - 401 2 5 0`

But I can browse to `http://localhost:53524/JSLib/general.js.map` fine in IE. So what's making the call for the map file (VS?) and how to I get it to use my credentials?

Comment: Assuming that your root folder is the `JSLib` folder, Does it work if you use `/general.js.map`? (If your root folder is the `Test` folder, `/JSLib/general.js.map`)

Comment: `Test` is the root, but it doesn't work with `JSLib/general.js.map` with or without a leading slash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I too have been experiencing this problem.  I am sorry to say that I do not know what the root of the problem is.  However, I have found a workaround.

Open your project properties and go to the 'TypeScript Build' tab.  In the 'Debugging' section, check the 'Specify root directory of the source maps' option and enter the value `$(ProjectDir)\Scripts`.

This works with Windows Authentication enabled and with the default 'sourceMappingUrl'.

Comment: Great simple solution, thanks! Much better than my PowerShell hack that edited the .js files

Comment: I reported the issue to MS, please add a vote for it? https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/853320/js-ts-map-files-do-not-work-in-vs2013rc2-with-windows-auth

Comment: I'm still seeing this problem on Update 2 RTM, anyone else?

Comment: Sorry for dumb question, but where is the 'TypeScript Build' tab located? I don't see it on project properties in VS 2013 Update 2.

Comment: On VS toolbar, Project -> <Project Name> Properties -> TypeScript Build tab will be on the bottom left. Or in VS Solution Explorer, right-click your project and choose Properties.

Comment: I don't see such tab there. One possibility is that this is happening because I'm having a different project type - it's a Win8.1 JavaScript modern app. I'm also having problems debugging TypeScript, while debugging JavaScript works fine.

Comment: Typescript Build tab does not exist in ASP.net Core 1.0 template in VS2015